# How to change Tracking ID for a list of GTM tags

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a list of close to 200 GTM tags on my Google Tag Manager workspace. We were using these tags for our UAT and production server. Now we are gathering Google analytics data separately for UAT and production.

How can I change the tracking ID for all the tags in GTM since I don't need them to be fired for the old tracking ID (UAT) ?

Answer (score 0):

On the "Tags" tab, open one of the Google Analytics tags.  Look for Google Analytics Settings.  Hopefully, it will have a variable assigned to the value.  Assuming it does, go to the "Variables" tab, and open the variable that corresponds to the Google Analytics Settings.  Updating the tracking ID in the variable will update it for all tags that reference that variable.

Comment: I did this for some of the tags which have variables assigned to them. In cases where i dont I will need to update them manually. 
Also, I would prefer to use the same tags for my UAT and production site. Is there any way if I can make copies of them?

Comment: To do a bulk update of settings, you could try exporting the container, then using a text editor on the resulting .json file to do a global replace of the new tracking ID with the other.  After the change, you could import the file to overwrite the existing settings.   I'm not familiar with the GTM's built-in tag copying functionality.  We use separate GTM containers for our test/production sites and use the import/export functionality to keep them in sync with only the Google Analytics Settings variable being different between the two.